# Transaction level consensus/endorsement in Hyperledger Fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, consensus

How to accomplish a transaction level consensus/endorsement between two organizations?

Let's say if `OrgA` sends Rs.5 to `OrgB`, `OrgB` should validate it and approve/decline based on some predefined agreement.

If `OrgB` expects Rs.15 and not Rs.10 for this transaction, it should raise a concern.

Where do we specify these details? I could see that the chaincode instantiate can specify policy but that is very generic as to how many endorsers should be there but not at a deeper level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you will need a mechanism to set separate policies for individual keys, rather than the general chaincode-level policy for all the keys in the chaincode. This feature is part of Fabric 1.3, which will have a release candidate version (rc1) out within next few days.

More details here:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8812